# Using Rob Camick's ListTableModel, but JTable doesnt show up

Tags: java, database, derby

I'm Using Camick's [ListTableModel](http://www.camick.com/java/source/ListTableModel.java) and [RowTableModel](http://www.camick.com/java/source/RowTableModel.java) from here http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/

However, the JTable is not showing up. Does anyone know why? I'm not getting any errors.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class AddressBook {

    JLabel name, address, phone, email;
    JTextField nameField, addressField, phoneField, emailField;
    JButton addPerson, addEntry, cancelEntry;
    JTable table;
    ListTableModel model;
    JDialog addEntryDialog;
    String[] headings = {"Name", "Address", "Phone #", "Email"};

    AddressBook() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        try {
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/AddressBook", "addressbook", "addressbook");
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM APP.ADDRESSBOOK");
            ListTableModel model = ListTableModel.createModelFromResultSet(rs);

            rs.close();
            //resultset.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();

        } catch(SQLException e){
            System.err.println(e);
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Address Book");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();

        addPerson = new JButton("New Entry");
        addPerson.addActionListener(listener);

        table = new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 490));

        //Add a person Dialog

        name = new JLabel("Name:");
        address = new JLabel("Address:");
        phone = new JLabel("Phone:");
        email = new JLabel("Email:");

        nameField = new JTextField(8);
        addressField = new JTextField(8);
        phoneField = new JTextField(8);
        emailField = new JTextField(8);

        addEntry = new JButton("Save");
        addEntry.addActionListener(listener);
        cancelEntry = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancelEntry.addActionListener(listener);

        addEntryDialog = new JDialog(frame, "Add a Person");
        addEntryDialog.setSize(190, 300);
        addEntryDialog.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        addEntryDialog.getContentPane().add(name);
        addEntryDialog.getContentPane().add(nameField);
        addEntryDialog.getContentPane().add(address);
        addEntryDialog.getContentPane().add(addressField);
        addEntryDialog.getContentPane().add(phone);
        addEntryDialog.getContentPane().add(phoneField);
        addEntryDialog.getContentPane().add(email);
        addEntryDialog.getContentPane().add(emailField);
        addEntryDialog.getContentPane().add(cancelEntry);
        addEntryDialog.getContentPane().add(addEntry);

        //end of Add a person dialog

        frame.getContentPane().add(addPerson);
        frame.getContentPane().add(table);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            JButton source = (JButton) event.getSource();

            if (source == addPerson) {
                addEntryDialog.setVisible(true);
            }
            if (source == addEntry) {
                //add to db
            }
            if (source == cancelEntry) {
                addEntryDialog.setVisible(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new AddressBook();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: If you comment out all of the database code and just make a default JTable(), can you get it to show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a second look at your code the problem is that you have defined the "model" variable as a class variable and an instance variable. The instance variable contains the data from the ResultSet. The class variable which is used to to create the table, is null. The code should be:

```
//ListTableModel model = ListTableModel.createModelFromResultSet(rs); 
model = ListTableModel.createModelFromResultSet(rs);
```

Comment: yup, this is probably it. i saw the scrollpane part (years of ui code debugging), but this looks to be the real problem. the scroll pane issue is only of no headers/etc.

Comment: Yes this was the problem, thanks. Also, is the only way to add headers is to use pass a TableColumnModel to JTableHeader and use setTable()?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're adding it to a scrollpane, and not adding the scrollpane to the content pane.  you're just adding the table.

without the scrollpane, you won't have any column headers.  and without any data, does the table have a preferred size of 0x0?

```
    frame.getContentPane().add(addPerson); 
    frame.getContentPane().add(**scroll**); 
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I added the scrollpane to contentpane and there is data in the database, however, nothing shows up still.

Comment: +1, I just did a test on a ResultSet with 0 rows. The preferred width does have a value since the model knows about the columns in the table. However, the preferred height is 0, so the table doesn't display. However, when the scroll pane is added to the frame the headings do show up as expected.