# MYSQL boolean return checkbox, not return tinyint

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

```
SELECT false as "Select" from Table_Name
```

The SQL run in derby I got this output:

[image]

The SQL run in MYSQL I got this output:

[image]

I want to create a JTable with a check box column by using the ResultSet.

It is workable when i use derby, my JTable got a column with check box.

But when I use MYSQL, my JTable got a column with 0.

The problem is found in 
[Which MySQL data type to use for storing boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289727/which-mysql-datatype-to-use-for-storing-boolean-values/289759#289759)

So now I'm thinking of:

1. Is it possible I can configure MYSQL until it can return check box like derby does?
2. Is there a function in MYSQL that can return boolean data type true/false? Not other data types.
3. Is it possible I can alter the ResultSet to get the check box?

My final objective is to create a JTable with a check box column as the first column and filled with data SELECT from database. Everyone wants the easy way.

Currently I'm using this method [Using Rob Camick's ListTableModel, but JTable doesnt show up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454220/using-rob-camicks-listtablemodel-but-jtable-doesnt-show-up)

```
//ListTableModel model = ListTableModel.createModelFromResultSet(rs); 
model = ListTableModel.createModelFromResultSet(rs);
```

Comment: `JTable`, by default, selects the appropriate cell renderer based on the class type of the value of the column.  Using a `DefaultTableModel`, for example, will result in it using the columns `class` type directly (`value.getClass()`), which may not return `Boolean`.  One solution is to set the column renderer directly, but you will need to be able to return a `true`/`false` value for the column value in order for it to work.

Comment: Have a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks MadProgrammer,

The custom renderer really works, and I found a suitable custom column renderer.

[CheckBoxTableCellRenderer.java](https://gate.ac.uk/gate/src/main/gate/swing/CheckBoxTableCellRenderer.java)

My final objective is achieved, to create a JTable with a check box column as the first column and filled with data SELECT from database. Everyone wants the easy way.